# Hive - How to make copy of transaction table

Tags: hadoop, hive, transactions, acid

Like we have [Create Table As Select (CTAS)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)) and [Create Table Like(CTL)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableLike)
already available in hive to create and copy the structure and data from source table, do we have the same feature available or do we could achieve this by any other ways..

Example - my current transaction table is which i wanted to copied as college_bckUp -

```
CREATE TABLE college(clg_id int,
clg_name string,
clg_loc string) 
clustered BY (clg_id) INTO 5 buckets 
stored AS orc TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');
```

Your help is appreciated in advance. Thanks

Comment: I don't think so there are any other ways.
If you need the data.. you can get the data from the HDFS path.

Comment: my requirement is where we have transactional table which we need to get another table like backup so that we that transactional will have any issues in future we should not lose the table data as after process we delete and update records, so we wanted to have one emergency backup then our duty in any failure would just alter the name of table and rerun the job again, nothing much if it will happen.

Comment: As previously commented, just copy out the HDFS data to back it up

Comment: The TBLPROPERTIES should be preserved with a CTL... Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

CTL will not create the new table with TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true'). All other settings will copy over, but you will have to modify the table after running CTL to set that property.